# Create Azure SQL table with results from a query in another database

Tags: sql, sql-server, azure

I need to create tables in a new Azure SQL database using query results from another database. I have tried using this kind of query but I get both a syntax error near 'Select' and an error that "reference to another database and/or server name is not supported in this version of SQL server." I am connected to both databases.

`Create Table dbo.AllDPCs As Select * From ( Query )`

I have also tried using SQL Management Studio to send an SSIS package, but it seems I do not have access to Azure Data Factory.

I have also tried running the query results to a csv file in OneDrive and then using bulk insert, but it appears that Azure Data Studio is having permission issues accessing OneDrive folders. I'm not sure if this is something I can solve on my own or if it requires that I ask IT to change my permissions.

I may need to reach out to our IT department to acquire permission to use Azure Data Factory, but I'd rather not take that route because it will mean multiple meetings and at least a month. Are there any alternatives that I should try before going to IT hat in hand?

- Tried to bulk insert csv - no permission to connect to OneDrive folder
- Tried this query but may not have permissions in Azure database to access other databases
  `Create Table dbo.AllDPCs As Select * From ( Query )`
- Tried to send a SSIS package through SQL Management Studio/Azure Data Factory but do not have the required permissions.

Comment: `CREATE TABLE ... FROM` isn't valid T-SQL. The syntax you want is `SELECT ... INTO ... FROM`. As for Azure, you've just tagged Azure, which isn't helpful. What are you actually using? An Azure SQL Database? An Azure Managed Instance? An Azure VM with SQL Server installed? Azure SQL Edge? Azure Synapse...? Something else?

Comment: Are you using Microsoft Azure Database or Azure Synapse? Because you have write `CTAS` query which is supported by Azure Synapse.

Comment: I'm using Azure Data Studio

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am having two azure SQL databases named db and db1 in my server I tried to create new table in db1 using student table which is in  db database with using below code

```
SELECT * 
INTO db1.dbo.student
FROM db.dbo.student
```

I got below error:

[image]

I used below process to rectify the issue.
I created master key and scoped credential in db1 database using below code:

```
CREATE MASTER KEY ENCRYPTION BY PASSWORD = '<Password>';

CREATE DATABASE SCOPED CREDENTIAL <name> WITH IDENTITY = '<userName>',
SECRET = '<Password>';
```

[image]

Created external detals with the created scoped credential using below code:

```
CREATE EXTERNAL DATA SOURCE <SourceDbName>
WITH
(
    TYPE=RDBMS,
    LOCATION='<serverName>.database.windows.net',
    DATABASE_NAME='<SourceDbName>',
    CREDENTIAL= <scopeedCredentialName>
);
```

[image]

Created External table with external data source using below code

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE [dbo].[newstudent](
    Id INT NOT NULL,
    Name varchar(50) NOT NULL
)
WITH
(
    DATA_SOURCE = db,
    SCHEMA_NAME = 'dbo',
    OBJECT_NAME = 'student'
)
```

[image]

I selected data using

```
SELECT * FROM newstudent
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for this Bhavani!

Unfortunately, I receive an error message that "user does not have permission to perform this action." It looks like I will have to engage my IT department after all.